# JQuery-UI resizable top & right bug when using containment

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've been working with jQuery-ui 1.11.4 and encountered a problem when working with a resizable div inside a container.
When the resizable div is adjacent to the bottom or right of the containing div, then the resize doesn't work.
Here's a jsfiddle demonstration:

http://jsfiddle.net/kcc6eq7c/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box">
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w"></div>

  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw"></div>
</div>

</div>

<style>
.container{
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  background-color:rgba(194,66,217,0.5);
}

.box {  
  top:400px;
  left:400px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(66,194,217,0.9);
}

.ui-resizable-helper { border: 1px dotted #00F;
}

.ui-resizable-handle {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

.ui-resizable-se {
  bottom: -5px;
  right: -5px;
}
</style>

<script>
var set_position = function(width, height){
  $('.ui-resizable-n').css('left', (width/2-4)+'px');
  $('.ui-resizable-e').css('top', (height/2-4)+'px');
  $('.ui-resizable-s').css('left', (width/2-4)+'px');
  $('.ui-resizable-w').css('top', (height/2-4)+'px');
};

$( ".box" ).resizable({ 
  containment:$(".container"),
  handles: {
    'n':'.ui-resizable-n', 
    'e':'.ui-resizable-e',
    's':'.ui-resizable-s',
    'w':'.ui-resizable-w',
    'ne': '.ui-resizable-ne',
    'se': '.ui-resizable-se',
    'sw': '.ui-resizable-sw',
    'nw': '.ui-resizable-nw'
  },
  grid: [ 10, 10 ],
  create: function( event, ui ) {
    var width = $(event.target).width();
    var height = $(event.target).height();
    set_position(width, height);
  },
  resize: function(event, ui){
    var width = $(event.target).width();
    var height = $(event.target).height();
    set_position(width, height);
  } 
});

$( ".box" ).draggable({
  grid: [ 10, 10 ]
});
</script>
```

Anyone encountered this and knows how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: After some debugging, I saw that the problem is that jQuery uses the offset of "this.helper" to determine if the div is still inside the container, but the helper does not get updated, so it thinks the div is at the container's limit. (Still no solution though...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the combination of `grid` and `containment`. When resizing `right` or `bottom`, only the `width/height` needs to be changed. But when resizing `left` and `top`, what actually happens is that the `left/top` position is changed as well as `width/height`.

Since you have `grid` option as well `position and width` change is not in continue. But, `containment` makes a calculation based on `left` position as well as `width` to see if the resizing gets out of the `containment`.

For example, when `left` is `400px` and `width` `100px` and `container` `500px`, it won't resize. Normally, resizing `left` would change `left position` and `width`, so calculation would allow resizing, but with `grid` activated, the change is not happening on each resize event, hence the `containment` prevents resizing. It certainly looks like a bug.

You could modify `resize` function of `containment` to take this into account. Something like this seems to work, but there may be some unwanted side effects:

```
//Access the resize function of containment
$(".box").resizable('instance').plugins.resize[0][1] = function (event) {
  ...

    //This is the only change to the original function.
    //It looks at the direction of the resize.
    //If axis is left or top then the calculations are made with position
    //instead of width, with an adjusment based on grid size
    if ((/w/.test(that.axis) ? that.position.left - 10 : woset) + that.size.width >= that.parentData.width) {

        that.size.width = that.parentData.width - woset;
        if (pRatio) {
            that.size.height = that.size.width / that.aspectRatio;
            continueResize = false;
        }
    }

    if ((/n/.test(that.axis) ? that.position.top - 10 : hoset) + that.size.height >= that.parentData.height) {
        that.size.height = that.parentData.height - hoset;
        if (pRatio) {
            that.size.width = that.size.height * that.aspectRatio;
            continueResize = false;
        }
    }

  ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8r7xyzhn/3/

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative` to .container